# Gorilla MUX routing with similar paths

Tags: go, gorilla

I'm using Gorilla mux in my golang api for routing. I have two paths that are similar: `/users/{id}` and `/users/settings`. When I make a call to the /users/settings endpoint, it is getting routed to the endpoint `/users/{id}`. How do I fix this?

```
router := mux.NewRouter()
router.HandleFunc("/users/{id}", usersController.GetUserDetail).Methods(http.MethodGet)
router.HandleFunc("/users/settings", usersController.GetSettings).Methods(http.MethodGet)
```

Comment: Use a regular expression for id

Comment: Register /settings first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the solution [Gorilla MUX routing with similar paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63943511/gorilla-mux-routing-with-similar-paths#comment113073005_63943511). I switched the ordering and now I am registering the settings first.

```
router.HandleFunc("/users/settings", usersController.GetSettings).Methods(http.MethodGet)

router.HandleFunc("/users/{id}", usersController.GetUserDetail).Methods(http.MethodGet)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regexp for route like id `/{id:[0-9]+}` it will match digits.